# Заполнение таблицы в SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql

Заполняю таблицу данными, тип данных дня рождения-date...

```
insert into Sotrdnik (TabelID, Familia,Name,Otchestvo, Adres, PhoneNumber,BirthdayData,DolgnostID,PodrazdelenieID,HolidayID,ListID,NewKvalifID) values

(100, 'Иванов','Александр','Сергеевич','Кирова 27-35', 3457889, 1960-03-21, 15, 7, 11, 1000,0001)
```

Возникает ошибка:

> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Что это???

Answer (score 3):

1960-03-21 возьми в кавычки

Comment: А формат даты не следует указывать?

Comment: а какого типа у тебя столбец в таблице?